# net-snmp snptranslate dosnt work for my MIB (snmpget does work)

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I add my own MIB module to net-snmp.

I put my Mib txt file under  - '/usr/local/share/snmp/mibs'

I see that if i change net-snmp files their the change is reflected , so this mibs are loaded correct.
It seems that it not load my MIB file from there.

When i run snmptranslate on my Mib like this:

```
snmptranslate .1.3.6.1.4.1.8077
```

I get:

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.8077
```

My MIB def:

```
TEST-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN
IMPORTS
    MODULE-IDENTITY, enterprises FROM SNMPv2-SMI;

testMib MODULE-IDENTITY
    DESCRIPTION
    "First draft"
    ::= { enterprises 8077}

testMibObject              OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= {testMib 1}


END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the location of snmp.conf you can use :

snmpd -Dread_config -H 2>&1 | grep "config path" | sort –u

then tell the tools to load this MIB

(examples)::

```
    snmpwalk -m +MY-MIB .....

        (load it for this command only)

or

    export MIBS=+MY-MIB

        (load it for this session only)

or

    echo "mibs +MY-MIB" >> $HOME/.snmp/snmp.conf

        (load it every time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find references for all situations:
[Using and loading MIBS](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:Using_and_loading_MIBS)

I saved your MIB to a file TEST-MIB, placed it under /usr/share/snmp/mibs and `snmptranslate` is able to find the `testMib` object, although your MIB is missing some fields to properly conform to the standard:

```
$ snmptranslate .1.3.6.1.4.1.8077
No log handling enabled - using stderr logging
Expected LAST-UPDATED (DESCRIPTION): At line 6 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/TEST-MIB
TEST-MIB::testMib
```

For making your MIBs conform you can use the tool [smidump](http://www.ibr.cs.tu-bs.de/projects/libsmi/smidump.html), which will tell you everything your MIB is missing to properly conform:

```
$ smidump /usr/share/snmp/mibs/TEST-MIB 
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/TEST-MIB:6: syntax error, unexpected DESCRIPTION, expecting LAST_UPDATED
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/TEST-MIB:13: missing MODULE-IDENTITY clause in SMIv2 MIB
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/TEST-MIB:10: unknown object identifier label `testMib'
smidump: module `/usr/share/snmp/mibs/TEST-MIB' contains errors, expect flawed output
smidump: aborting due to severe parsing errors
smidump: use the -k option to force continuation
```

Comment: This wasnt enough. i place it there, but in additional i need to create snmp.conf and define the mib file there

Comment: Did you already create this snmp.conf file with something like this inside?

`mibs +TEST-MIB`

 (In my system it works without this, but it might help)

Comment: I didnt have this file, so i added this file with 2 lines: mibfile and mibs (i think that mibfile is sufficient) , but without this file it wasnt work unless you do export for the session